# What git server solution to use on windows and active directory?

Tags: windows, git, version-control, active-directory, gitstack

We are looking for the best solution for setting up a local git server.
Our wishlist is

- run on Windows Server 2008R2
- small team - less than ten developers
- easy to set up
- easy to use
- active directory authentication of users
- robust
- web gui would be nice
- free would be nice

Solutions we're thinking about

- gitosis looks like a hassle to set up and has no web gui
- bare git on a windows file share - seems easy but no web gui of course
- gitstack looks good but is not free

Any advice?

Comment: This probably doesn't belong on Stack Overflow, there's no programming specific problem to solve here. Also, are you really worried about gitstacks pricing? 3 hours messing around with poor tools and you've already lost the money gitstack would have cost... You should give it a go (considering they have a free trial) and see if it works for you.

Comment: The problem with cost is ironically not the price but the trouble of buying something via enterprise bureaucracy.

Comment: Note that gitosis is no longer maintained. Someone created [gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/) to replace it, which has more functionality. Though, it is more linux orientend than windows.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn That's true, but thankfully you're using git which is software-independent!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have made a great experience with [Atlassian's Stash](http://www.atlassian.com/software/stash/overview).

It costs 10$ for 10 Developers and supports Projects with multiple git repos.

You have nothing to setup since it comes with integrated git, ssh and http server. (Just the server itself duh - but its not that hard, 30 minutes should be enough)

It provides a nice Webgui. You should check it out, there is a test licence for 30 days I guess.

Answer (score 1):

We are using [GitLab](http://gitlab.org/) which is a web front end to gitolite. User authentication to the web server can be done using LDAP / ActiveDirectory although the git commit access is done via ssh keys. This UI helps with managing the keys and repository access though. GitExtensions has some dialogs to help our users in generating the keys to be uploaded (a one time operation). I suspect anything fancier than this will be commercial.

Comment: it seems like gitlab isn't for windows